# Console.log in a Java Back-end

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm using Java with Spring Boot in IntelliJ Community edition. 
I usually use console.log() in the front-end to debug my code and see the value of a variable. 
Here in the back-end I try to do the same using `System.out.println`.
For example

```
System.out.println("page is" + query.page());
return dslContext.select(...
```

I'm looking at the IntelliJ terminal but not getting anything back there.

Comment: Can you verify the method gets executed?

Comment: @Glains I'm new to Java for BE. How can I do that?
I know that the return part is being executed.

Comment: Put the `System.out.println("In here");` right at the beginning of the method, maybe something is breaking and hence not getting printed.

Comment: @NicholasK Still not getting anything back in the Terminal and the application is running.

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including the source code?

Comment: How exactly are you running the application?

Comment: @yole `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=local`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the logger from `java.util.logging.Logger`

```
    private static final long serialVersionUID=1L;
    public static Logger logger=Logger.getLogger("global");
    //do some
    logger.info("page is"+query.page());
```

Comment: Where should I add these lines?
`Cannot resolve symbol Logger`

Comment: This after the class declaration `private static final long serialVersionUID=1L;` after add this `public static Logger logger=Logger.getLogger("global");` and when you need to use logger you do `logger.info("page is"+query.page())`;

Comment: needed to import `import java.util.logging.Logger;` and still can't see any result in the terminal

Comment: The logger output might go to a file, depending on configuration. Still a mystery why System.out.println didn't work

Comment: This doesn't actually answer why `System.out.println` didn't work, even if using a logging framework is better practice